# Given $T(n) = T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n}$, show that The Master Theorem is not applicable to this recurrence equation

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Given
$$T(n) = T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n},$$ show that The Master Theorem is not applicable to this recurrence equation, hence show that $T(n)=O(\log n)$ using algebraic substitution given $T(1) =1$.

Comment: Your notation is potentially ambiguous.  I have edited the question to format the mathematics, under the assumption that $T(n-1) + 1/n$ is mean to be understood as $T(n-1) + \frac{1}{n}$.  If you meant $\frac{T(n-1)+1}{n}$, can you please edit your question to reflect this?

Answer (score 1):

Part 1. You cannot apply the master theorem as the critical exponent is not well defined as the base of the logarithm would be essentially $1$.

Part 2. Hint: Using the substitution $T(1)=1$, you get $T(n)= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$.  Next use the property that $\lim_{n\to\infty} [ T(n)-\log(n) ]= \gamma$, where  $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

Comment: Use `\lim_{n\to\infty}` $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$ instead. Same for `\log` $\log$ instead of `log` $log$